# AngularJs - ng-repeat - How can I get the key of an element inside a list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON structure (myTags) like this:

```
[ 
  { "tag1" : [{"id" : 1} , {"id" : 2 }] } ,
  { "tag2" : [{"id" : 3} , {"id" : 4 }] }
]
```

In a ng-repeat block I want to access tag1 and tag2.

I tried using key val like this:

```
<div ng-repeat ="(key,val) in myTags">
    <div class="block">
        <a href="">{{key}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But key is 0 and 1 instead of tag1 and tag2. How can I access them?

Comment: Yes, myTags in an array like the one showed above.

Comment: Verify my edit.  I made it an actual array by closing it with a `]`

Comment: It was a typo, myTags is an actual array with that format, returned by a REST service.

Comment: Ok.  Cool.  I just wanted to make sure, since editing code in a question can be dubious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned, you have the nesting incorrect here.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in myTags">
   <div ng-repeat="(key, array) in tag">
     <div class="block">
       <a href="">{{key}}</a>
       {{array}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IwxeUgVF7SkMp8xRAvH7?p=preview

You want to first output each object, and then loop through each object and separate it's key from the inner array of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can loop the properties of the object using a nested ng-repeat like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in myTags">
    <div class="block" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
      <a href="">{{key}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

working example:  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/oLYrro

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, I get 1 and 2 printed but I need tag1 and tag2

Comment: Yes this works, like ryanyuyu suggested  <div ng-repeat="obj in myTags">
          <div class="block" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
            <a href="">{{key}}</a>
          </div>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

Angular is working as expected.  Since `myTags` is an array, the key will of course be the index of each object.  The thing you think of as a key is really just some changing property name, which isn't setup in a particularly helpful way.

I suggest changing your service to return things in a different format.  For example, if your `myTags` were an object instead of an array, your code works fine.  Your object ideally looks like this:

```
myTags = { 
   "tag1" : [{"id" : 1} , {"id" : 2 }] ,
   "tag2" : [{"id" : 3} , {"id" : 4 }]
};
```

See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPmzrj48COHOAzpMFXHF?p=preview).

---

If you are handcuffed to format in your question, you should be pulling data off each object within your array.  [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996476/4320665) is a good start for this.  Changing your markup to something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat ="obj in myTags">
    <!-- each obj is an object with a single property whose value is an array-->
    <div class="block" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
        <!-- only one key in the object you provided-->
        <a href="">{{key}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo for this alternative](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgLt0kHm0oiZ4PdLb7xX?p=preview)